# recovering errors with CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, cloudkit, ckerror

After getting `.partialFailure` `CKError`, I've been trying to recover id's and corresponding errors but I'm having problems...

**Right now I'm using:**

```
print("pE \(error.partialErrorsByItemID) or \(error.userInfo[CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey])")

    if let dictionary = error.userInfo[CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey] as? [NSObject: Error] {

print("partialErrors #\(dictionary.count)")    // <-- Not reaching this...
```

**I've also tried the following:**

```
if let dictionary = error.partialErrorsByItemID {   // <-- error.pEBIID returns nil
```

and:

```
if let dictionary = error.userInfo[CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey] as? [CKRecord : CKError /* and Error */] {    // <-- but neither triggers the if-let
```

The first print is showing this in the console (I switched the open tags leftward so that they wouldn't be interpreted as html):

```
pE nil or Optional({
">CKRecordID: 0x7b95ace0; CentralTableView:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>" = ">CKError 0x7a7e4cf0: \"Server Record Changed\" (14/2004); server message = \"record to insert already exists\"; uuid = B7AD7528-D8AE-4DCB-91FF-16B5271110F5; container ID = \"iCloud.com.yadayadayada\">";
})
```

As I understand from the documentation I should be getting a `NSDictionary<CKRecordID, (CK)Error>` back from `userInfo` dictionary with `CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey` and a `NSDictionary<NSObject, Error>` from the `partialErrorsByItemID` method. Based on the first print, the method isn't working in this situation but key is giving me a dictionary of CKRecordID and CKError. **I don't see why the second print isn't getting reached?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation, you get back an `NSDictionary`, not a Swift dictionary.

Try:

```
if let dictionary = error.userInfo[CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey] as? NSDictionary {
    print("partialErrors #\(dictionary.count)")
}
```